# Mysql data include text style to html

Tags: mysql, html, textstyle

In mysql database, table named "project" contains text data below. Text style(e.g. < h1 >) is included together.

[image]

I want to show "description" data of "project" table {{project.description}} in monitor like:

[image]

But it keeps showing as it is.

[image]

What tags should I use?

I already used div, source, resource, code, pre, p...

Also, I used iframe tag but I don't know how to use...

My html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<p>
{{ project.description }}
</p>
{% endblock %}
```

This template is extended from layout.html and I just wrote p tag example.

Comment: Well, can you show us the code you used?

Comment: @Swellar I extends from basic layout and this is example for using p tag

Comment: Please add it to the question

Comment: @Swellar OK Thx

Comment: escape html in templating script to render the html on pages.

Comment: @imdzeeshan I don't understand what is "escape html". Could you explain in detail?

Comment: what template you are using?